# how do I get my google sheet app verified with Google?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google sheet that takes several weeks from a staff schedule and post it to a shared calendar using apps script. I want to share this sheet and it's embedded script with my colleagues.

When it runs the first time they need to give it permissions until I "verify this app with Google". What does this mean and how do I go about it?
/thanks